# Attaching file with SSIS by matching filename with value in SQL table

Tags: ssis, sendmail, attachment

I have a SQL table which structures as

```
Serial  EMAIL
543     ali@hotmail.com
789     paul@gmail.com
485     paul@gmail.com
654     sam@yahoo.com
```

and then I have pdf attachments in a folder where filenames are like

```
Happy 543.pdf
Happy 789.pdf
Happy 485.pdf
Happy 654.pdf
```

I want to match each serial number with filename's last 3 characters and then email that particular pdf to corresponding email address.

I have done extracting email address from table storing in a table and then using that email address with SENDMAIL task `TOline` expression property. Email goes according to plan. 
But when it comes to attach file when I dont understand how would i attach corresponding file with email.
Someone please help
it would be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your package looks something like this

[image]

### Create variables

The use of Variables help separate the dabblers from the professionals. This is true because of the simple fact you can put a breakpoint on a package to inspect a variable. The same cannot be said of inspecting the expression on a task.

[image]
As you can see, I have a few variables created.

- CurrentID, String, populated from my foreach loop
- Recipient, String, populated from my foreach loop
- FolderInput, String, base folder where files will exist
- ResultSet, Object, populated in the Execute SQL Task, shredded in Foreach loop
- CurrentFile, String, defines the full path to a file. This is an Expression of `@[User::FolderInput] + "\\Happy " + (DT_WSTR, 3) @[User::CurrentID]+ ".pdf"`

As the Foreach loop enumerates, the value of CurrentID and Recipient change. By virtue of CurrentID changing, my mapping will be updated for each person so when the send mail task fires, it sends the correct file along.

Not addressed - dynamic file names and subfolders. The expression on CurrentFile assumes the file will exist and it will always be named `Happy NNN.pdf` where NNN is the CurrentID value. If you could have `Hap 123.pdf`, `Joyous 123.pdf`, `Subfolder\Happy 123.pdf` etc, then you're going to have do work, probably in a script task, to derive the value of the file name. That's a separate SO question.

### Express yourself

On the Send Mail Task, the third tab exposes the Expressions for this task. This is the most powerful option on every Task in your SSIS toolkit. Here we will specify the recipient is the variable `@[User::Recipient]` and the file we are sending is `[@User::CurrentFile]`

[image]

One, fairly important thing to note here. If the file does not exist, the Send Mail Task will fail.

Comment: The use of Variables help separate the dabblers from the professionals. ...... and there is no doubt about that, i am relatively new to variables... i have stored email in variable already which i forgot to mention. now i will work on solution you have provided... and thank u very much for your kind help. i am grateful

Comment: If you find answers useful, click the up arrow next to them. Click down if they are not. Since this is your question, you may also click the check mark if the answer solves your problem.